# ejabberd resources log

Tags: resources, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm looking for a module or trick to see, what resources are logged in to the ejabberd server.

I could log in with a script to one account and fetch all presence stanzas, but I hope there is a better way of getting the data.

Btw all user accounts from the ejabberd server are on all user rosters, so everyone sees everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the following:

`ejabberdctl user_resources $USER $HOST`

On my server this lists the resources for the specified user which are currently connected to the server.